# How does Docker Swarm implement volume sharing?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-machine

Docker Swarm can manage two types of storage:

`volume` and `bind`

While `bind` is not suggested by Docker Documentation since it creates a binding between a local directory (on each swarm Node) to a task, the `volume` implementation is not mentioned, so I don't understand how volumes are shared between tasks?

- How does Docker Swarm shares volumes between nodes?
- Where are volumes saved (on a manager? And if there is more than one manager?)
- Is there no problem between nodes if it's running on different machines on different networks?
- Does it create a VPN?

Comment: Does Swarm share volumes? It's about a year ago that I dealt with docker swarm, but I think swarm is NOT responsible for sharing volumes between nodes. If you want your nodes to share the same volume, you have to use volume plugins like azure volumedriver.

Comment: What work for us is using lsync between nodes...

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Swarm Mode itself does not do anything different with volumes, it runs any volume mount command you provide on the node where the container is running. If your volume mount is local to that node, then your data will be saved locally on that node. There is no built in functionality to move data between nodes automatically.

There are some software based distributed storage solutions like GlusterFS, Rook, Ceph, and Longhorn. Many of these are focused on integration with Kubernetes, which won't help in Swarm.

The typical result is you either need to manage replication of storage within your application (e.g. etcd and other raft based algorithms) or you perform your mounts on an external storage system (hopefully with its own high availability). Mounting an external storage system has two options, block or file based. Block based storage (e.g. EBS) typically comes with higher performance, but is limited to only be mounted on a single node. For this, you will typically need a 3rd party volume plugin driver to give your docker node access to that block storage. File based storage (e.g. EFS) has lower performance, but is more portable, and can be simultaneously mounted on multiple nodes, which is useful for a replicated service.

The most common file based network storage is NFS (this is the same protocol used by EFS). And you can mount that without any 3rd party plugin drivers. The unfortunately named "local" volume plugin driver that docker ships with give you the option to pass any values you want to the mount command with driver options, and with no options, it defaults to storing volumes in the docker directory /var/lib/docker/volumes. With options, you can pass it the NFS parameters, and it will even perform a DNS lookup on the NFS hostname (something you don't have with NFS normally). Here's an example of the different ways to mount an NFS filesystem using the local volume driver:

```
  # create a reusable volume
  $ docker volume create --driver local \
      --opt type=nfs \
      --opt o=nfsvers=4,addr=192.168.1.1,rw \
      --opt device=:/path/to/dir \
      foo

  # or from the docker run command
  $ docker run -it --rm \
    --mount type=volume,dst=/container/path,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=nfs,\"volume-opt=o=nfsvers=4,addr=192.168.1.1\",volume-opt=device=:/host/path \
    foo

  # or to create a service
  $ docker service create \
    --mount type=volume,dst=/container/path,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=nfs,\"volume-opt=o=nfsvers=4,addr=192.168.1.1\",volume-opt=device=:/host/path \
    foo

  # inside a docker-compose file
  ...
  volumes:
    nfs-data:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: nfs
        o: nfsvers=4,addr=192.168.1.1,rw
        device: ":/path/to/dir"
  ...
```

If you use the compose file example at the end, note that changes to a volume (e.g. updating the server path or address) are not reflected in existing named volumes for as long as they exist. You need to either rename your volume, or delete it, to allow swarm to recreate it with new values.

The other common issue I see in most NFS usage is "root squash" being enabled on the server. This results in permission issues when containers running as root attempt to write files to the volume. You also have similar UID/GID permission issues where the container UID/GID is the one that needs permissions to write to the volume, which may require directory ownership and permissions to be adjusted on the NFS server.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I only got 3-4 of your 9 acronyms (GA, EE, HA, EBS, EFS, NFS, DNS, UID, GID ) though.  Would be useful to define them?

Comment: A few of those references were stale, so I removed them. EBS and EFS are AWS services, so if you aren't in or familiar with AWS, ignore those. Understanding NFS, UIDs, an GIDs are a prerequisite for setting up a network storage solution and are better done with documentation and blog posts.

Comment: @BMitch As far as I understand, MinIO is an EBS to be self hosted like the one you got in an AWS service, to storage objects too, instead of raw files (maybe you won't mention to not confuse more in the answer).

Answer (score 88):

What you're asking about is a common question. Volume data and the features of what that volume can do are managed by a volume driver. Just like you can use different network drivers like `overlay`, `bridge`, or `host`, you can use different volume drivers.

Docker and Swarm only come with the standard `local` driver out of the box. It doesn't have any awareness of Swarm, and it will just create new volumes for your data on whichever node your service tasks are scheduled on. This is usually not what you want.

You want a 3rd party driver plugin that is Swarm aware, and will ensure the volume you created for a service task is available on the right node at the right time.  Options include using "Docker for AWS/Azure" and its included [CloudStor](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-azure/persistent-data-volumes/) driver, or the popular open source [REX-Ray](https://rexray.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) solution.

There are lots of 3rd party volume drivers, which you can find on the [Docker Store](https://store.docker.com/search?category=volume&q=&type=plugin).

Comment: can hadoop act as such a shared volume?

Answer (score 22):

My solution for our locally hosted swarm:
every worker node has mounted an nfs-share, provided by our fileserver on `/mnt/docker-data`. When I define volumes in my services compose files, I set the device to some path under `/mnt/docker-data`, for example:

```
volumes:
  traefik-logs:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      device: /mnt/docker-data/services/traefik/logs
      type: none
```

With this solution, docker creates the volume on every node, the service is deployed to and - surprise - there is data already, because it is the same path, which was used by the volume on the other node.

If you take a closer look at the nodes filesystem, you see that mounts to my fileserver mount are created under `/var/lib/docker/volumes`, see here:

```
root@node-3:~# df -h
Dateisystem                                                                                                   Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
[...]
fs.mydomain.com:/srv/shares/docker-data/services/traefik/logs                                 194G    141G   53G   73% /var/lib/docker/volumes/traefik_traefik-logs/_data
```

Comment: Does this work in a hybrid swarm?  i.e. Windows node.

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 12):

My solution for AWS EFS, that works:

1. [Create EFS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/gs-step-two-create-efs-resources.html) (don't forget to open NFS port 2049 at security group)
2. Install nfs-common package:

   `sudo apt-get install -y nfs-common`
3. Check if your efs works:

   ```
   mkdir efs-test-point
   sudo chmod go+rw efs-test-point
   ```

   ```
   sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport [YOUR_EFS_DNS]:/ efs-test-point
   ```

   ```
   touch efs-test-point/1.txt
   sudo umount efs-test-point/
   ls -la efs-test-point/
   ```

   > directory must be empty

   ```
   sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport [YOUR_EFS_DNS]:/ efs-test-point
   ```

   `ls -la efs-test-point/`

   > file 1.txt must exists
4. Configure docker-compose.yml file:

   ```
   services:
     sidekiq:
       volumes:
         - uploads_tmp_efs:/home/application/public/uploads/tmp
     ...
   volumes:
     uploads_tmp_efs:
       driver: local
       driver_opts:
         type: nfs
         o: addr=[YOUR_EFS_DNS],nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2
         device: [YOUR_EFS_DNS]:/
   ```

Answer (score 2):

by default swarm will always look for local volume driver ,so the best way is to

1. create nfs share i.e. `yum -y install nfs-utils`
2. export it in /etc/exports as below,
   `/root/nfshare 192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_root_squash)`
3. open required ports, in my case i did below,
   `firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service mountd ; firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service rpc-bind ; firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service nfs ;  firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port 2049/tcp`
4. mount newly created share on docker worker nodes & then
5. `docker service create --name my-web --replicas 3 -p 80:80 --mount 'type=volume,source=nfshare,target=/usr/share/nginx/html/,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=nfs,volume-opt=device=:/root/nfshare,"volume-opt=o=addr=192.168.1.8,rw"' nginx:latest`
6. in above example i have created nfshare on 192.168.1.8 host & exported using /etc/exports file
7. started daemon(s)
   `systemctl start nfs-server rpcbind & systemctl enable nfs-server rpcbind`
8. exportfs -r to changes take effect
9. /root/nfshare have my own index.html
   10.check volume-drive entry carefully , it can be external also & whoa it worked for me
10. for more reference https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: I don't like all the NFS solutions mentioned in the answers. It will create a single point of failure. Either use a distributed file system, like GlusterFS, or just try to get rid of the need for distributed volumes (e.g. use a DB that can support sharing files, like GridFS in MongoDB).

Comment: I like the GridFS idea. For me GlusterFS was a complete glusterf* that would continually disconnect and reset everything when deployed to digital ocean nodes. Massive single point of failure. I looked at GridFS and read the following though: "Do not use GridFS if you need to update the content of the entire file atomically." So if you plan on updating files, like SSL certs for example, there has to be something better...