# Does Docker swarm ignore VOLUME commands from Dockerfiles?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-volume

We are deploying a stack, the compose file list two services:

- mediawiki
- mySQL

We saw that the [mysql Dockerfile has a `VOLUME` directive](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.7/Dockerfile#L73), to persist the databases to a Docker volume

Yet, if we `docker stack rm` then `docker stack deploy` our compose file, we lose all the database content.

Is that the expected behaviour? What would be the rationale for it?

Answer (score 2):

Swarm mode doesn't build docker images, so it's safe to say that docker swarm is ignoring every line of your Dockerfile. The resulting image will have a volume identified which will be created when the container is run, whether that is inside or outside of swarm mode. If you do not specify a volume mount at runtime, docker will give you an anonymous volume at that location, which is difficult to identify later on, and local to the node where the container is running. With a new stack, the previous anonymous volume won't be used, and in various situations, the anonymous volume can be automatically deleted (e.g. when containers are configured to automatically delete on exit, which I'm not sure if it applies to swarm mode).

A named volume can make the data easier to reused in a single node cluster. When you get to a multi-node cluster, you need to move this data off of the node where the container is running. For details on how to use something like NFS for external data storage, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52151840/596285) to a related question.

Comment: I provided the Dockerfile for a reference of how the mysql image was created, of course the local swarm commands never get to read it. Yet, what you describe is what I would expect Docker swarm to do (giving me an anonymous volume). Yet it seems this volume is not persisted across different deployments of the stack, which surprises me. *edit:* Your edit made it clear that my expectation was wrong, thank you!

Comment: @AdN Anonymous volumes are... anonymous. They have no details on why they were created, what image they were associated with, what mount point they were mounted at, so swarm mode cannot easily reuse them between different deploys of the stack. At the very least, you want a named volume.

Answer (score 1):

The Dockerfile has a volume but you probably haven't mounted that volume as accessible outside of that container, which means it probably isn't being pulled out to the persistent overlay storage to be shared between containers/container deployments.

In your database service in the docker-compose.yml file you're going to need a `volumes` section. I'm omitting your current setup since you didn't provide it and I'm going to replace it with ellipses `...`.

```
mySQL:
  ...
  volumes:
    - mySQL-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

This tells the system that you want to persist the `/var/lib/mysql` directory outside of the container in your shared overlay that I randomly named `mySQL-data`.

Comment: Is `mySQL-data` a named volume? If so, should it also be declared at the top-level of the compose file?

Comment: You don't need it in a stand alone section like you need it for networks. I believe this should work as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Being in swarm mode is not relevant in this case.

If you are only relying on the anonymous volume defined in the Dockerfile, running a new container will create and mount a new fresh volume. You need to specifically mount a named volume at container start (in your case add it in your compose file) to remount the same volume between runs.

If you need to remount a lost data volume, it might still be possible if you did not prune data on your server. You will just need to find the relevant volume (that has a hash as name), eventually rename it and remount it in your new container.

I played the following scenario to illustrate my point:

First get the image and have a look:

```sh
$ docker pull mysql:latest
$ docker image inspect mysql:latest
```

From this last command we can see there is a volume declared for `/var/lib/mysql`

I'm on my dev machine. Cleaned up everything so I have no volumes at this time

```sh
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
$
```

Start a container then look at volumes again

```sh
$ docker run -d --name test -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1 mysql:latest 
37a92341f52b189d00636d1f03ecfbd4e3e7e5d55b685f5ec254971d7732566c
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               50f9810d13271c7c91b7e025e139db480f288a936f0a55f85d9580ef3aa83af7
```

Now add some data to the container

```sh
$ docker exec -it test bash
root@37a92341f52b:/# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  [... snip ...]
mysql> create database testso;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
mysql> use testso;
Database changed
mysql> create table test (id int not null primary key);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)
mysql> insert into test values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
mysql> select * from test;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
root@37a92341f52b:/# exit
$
```

Create a new container

```sh
$ docker rm -f test
test
$ docker run -d --name test -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1 mysql:latest
79148de09d7a3e13db338da133cfd7d44fe3590dc1c7ffe6129722c5c6baea21
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               50f9810d13271c7c91b7e025e139db480f288a936f0a55f85d9580ef3aa83af7
local               ef6fb2647c11c10ef98d25ca0dc2bd43231729ed18386c65768a0ad808fca93b
```

As you can see we have a second volume for the new container. I will not show this here but if I connect, the data is empty as in your case. Now let's try to recover.

First a little cleanup

```sh
$ docker rm -f test
test
$ docker volume rm ef6fb2647c11c10ef98d25ca0dc2bd43231729ed18386c65768a0ad808fca93b
ef6fb2647c11c10ef98d25ca0dc2bd43231729ed18386c65768a0ad808fca93b
```

We want to have a human readable name but we cannot rename a volume. What I did is mount the old one and a new named volume in a busybox container to transfer the data over.

```sh
$ docker run -it --rm -v 50f9810d13271c7c91b7e025e139db480f288a936f0a55f85d9580ef3aa83af7:/mysql/old -v mysql_data:/mysql/new busybox:latest 
/ # cd /mysql/
/mysql # mv old/* new/
/mysql # exit
```

We now have this new volume and we can get rid off the anonymous one

```sh
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               50f9810d13271c7c91b7e025e139db480f288a936f0a55f85d9580ef3aa83af7
local               mysql_data
$ docker volume rm 50f9810d13271c7c91b7e025e139db480f288a936f0a55f85d9580ef3aa83af7
50f9810d13271c7c91b7e025e139db480f288a936f0a55f85d9580ef3aa83af7
```

And finally we remount the named volume in a fresh mysql container to get our data back

```sh
$ docker run -d --name test -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1 -v mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql mysql:latest
3f6eff0b7660f3f8e9518564affc6555acb17184845156099d18300b3e76f4a2
$ docker exec -it test bash
root@3f6eff0b7660:/# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  [... snip ...]

mysql> use testso
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> select * from test;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```