# Share volume in docker swarm for many nodes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-blob-storage, docker-swarm, volume

I'm facing a big challenge. Trying run my app on 2 VPS in docker swarm. Containers that use volumes should use shared volume between nodes.

My solution is:

1. Use plugin glusterFS and mount volume on every node using nfs. NFS generate single point of failure so when something go wrong my data are gone. (it's not look good maybe im wrong)
2. Use Azure Storage - store data as blob ( Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 ). But my main is problem how can i connect to azure storage using docker-compose.yaml? I should declarate volume in every service that use volume and declare volume in volume section. I don't have idea how to do that.

Docker documentation about it is gone. Should be here https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-azure/persistent-data-volumes/.

Another option is use https://hub.docker.com/r/docker4x/cloudstor/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated but last update was 2 years ago so its probably not supported anymore.

Do i have any other options and which share volume between nodes is best solution?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/47756029/596285

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways of dealing with creating persistent volumes in docker swarm, none of them particularly satisfactory:

First up, a simple way is to use nfs, glusterfs, iscsi, or vmware to multimount the same SAN storage volume onto each docker swarm node. Services just mount volumes as `/mnt/volumes/my-sql-workload`
On the one hand its really simple, on the other hand there is literally no access control and you can easilly accidentally load services pointing at each others data.

Next, commercial docker volume plugins for SANs. If you are lucky and possess a Pure Storage, NetApp or other such SAN array, some of them still offer docker volume plugins. [Trident](https://netapp-trident.readthedocs.io/en/stable-v21.04/) for example if you have a NetApp.

Third. if you are in the cloud, the legacy swarm offerings on Azure and Aws included a built in "cloudstor" volume driver but you need to dig really deep to find it in their legacy offering.

Four, there are a number of opensource or free volume plugins that will mount volumes from nfs, glusterfs or other sources. But most are abandoned or very quiet. The most active I know of is [marcelo-ochoa/docker-volume-plugins](https://github.com/marcelo-ochoa/docker-volume-plugins)

I wasn't particularly happy with how those plugins mounted pre-existing volumes, but made operations like `docker volume create` hard, so I made my [own](https://github.com/chrisbecke/glusterfs-volume), but really

[Swarm Cluster Volume Support with CSI Plugins](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/39624) is hopefully going to drop in 2021¹. Which hopefully is a solid rebuttal to all the problems above.

¹Its now 2022 and the next version of Docker has not yet gone live with CSI support. Still we wait.

Comment: Docker 23.0 Whats new: Add experimental support for SwarmKit cluster volumes (CSI)
https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/23.0/#new
At time of writing latest major is Docker 24

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a good solution could be to create a GlusterFS cluster, configure a single volume and mount it in every Docker Swarm node (i.e. in  `/mnt/swarm-storage`).

Then, for every Container that needs persistent storage, bind-mount a subdirectory of the GlusterFS volume inside the container.

Example:

```
services:
  my-container:
    ...
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /mnt/swarm-storage/my-container
        target: /a/path/inside/the/container
```

This way, every node shares the same storage, so that a given container could be instantiated indifferently on every cluster node.

You don't need any Docker plugin for a particular storage driver, because the distributed storage is transparent to the Swarm cluster.

Lastly, GlusterFS is a distributed filesystem, designed to not have a single point of failure and you can cluster it on as many node you like (contrary to NFS).

Comment: I had a lot of problems with GlusterFS. I had to write my own service to get the volume to stop, then start, then mount. Also, I had horrible performance with Laravel. I also had problems with Stale File Handles. Then I had to deal with ACL problems as well. It's definitely not faster than an NVME mounted directly to the VM. I feel rsync to a secondary node would be better.